# Getting error while creating BufferedImage

Tags: java, ocr, bufferedimage

***CODE 1***

```
/*
   Java code for making the image grayscale, then binarizing it.
 */
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.lang.Object;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class lineremoval {

    private static BufferedImage binarizedImage;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File orignal_name = new File("photot.png");
        binarizedImage = ImageIO.read(orignal_name);
        ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight();

        BufferedImage    bmp = new BufferedImage(binarizedImage.getWidth(), binarizedImage.getHeight(),binarizedImage.getType());
        for(int i=0; i<binarizedImage.getWidth(); i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<binarizedImage.getHeight(); j++) {
                int red;
                red = new Color(binarizedImage.getRGB(i,j)).getRed();
                int alpha = new Color(binarizedImage.getRGB(i,j)).getAlpha();
                int newPixel;
                newPixel = colorToRGB(alpha, red,red,red);
                bmp.setRGB(i, j, newPixel);

            }
        }
        writeImage(bmp,0);

    }
    public static int FindBottomOfLine(BufferedImage bitmap, int topOfLine)
    {
        int x=0;
        boolean no_black_pixel;
        no_black_pixel = false;
        int to_match;
        while (no_black_pixel == false)
        {
            topOfLine++;
            int white=new Color(bitmap.getRGB(0,0)).getRed();
            no_black_pixel = true; 
            for (x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth() && topOfLine < bitmap.getHeight(); x++)
            {
                to_match = new Color(bitmap.getRGB(x,topOfLine)).getRed();
                if (to_match!=white)
                    no_black_pixel = false;
            }
        }
        return topOfLine - 1;
    }
    public static int  ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight()
    {
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        boolean line_present = true;
        ArrayList<Integer> line_top = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000);
        ArrayList<Integer> line_bottom = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000);
        while (line_present)
        {
            x = 0;
            y = FindNextLine(binarizedImage, y, x);
            if (y == -1)
                break;
            if (y >= binarizedImage.getHeight())
            {
                line_present = false;
            }
            if (line_present)
            {
                line_top.add(y);
                y = FindBottomOfLine(binarizedImage, y) + 1;
                line_bottom.add(y);
            }
        }

        return 1;
    }
    private static void writeImage(BufferedImage bmp,int number) throws IOException {
        String strI = Integer.toString(number); 
        File file = new File("output"+strI+".png");
        try {
                    ImageIO.write(bmp, "png", file);
            }catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Not worked");
            }
            finally {
                    System.out.println("Works fine");
            }

    }
    private static int colorToRGB(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {

        int newPixel = 0;
        newPixel += alpha;
        newPixel = newPixel << 8;
        newPixel += red; newPixel = newPixel << 8;
        newPixel += green; newPixel = newPixel << 8;
        newPixel += blue;

        return newPixel;

    }
    public static int FindNextLine(BufferedImage bitmap, int y,int x)
    {
        if (y >= bitmap.getHeight())
            return -1;
        int white=new Color(bitmap.getRGB(0,0)).getRed();
        int to_match = new Color(bitmap.getRGB(x,y)).getRed();
        while (to_match==white)
        {

            x++;
            if (x == bitmap.getWidth())
            {
                x = 0;
                y++;
            }
            if (y >= bitmap.getHeight())
            {
                break;
            }
            to_match = new Color(bitmap.getRGB(x,y)).getRed();
        }
        return y < bitmap.getHeight() ? y : -1;
    }

}
```

***CODE 2***

```
 import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.lang.Object;
    import java.lang.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    import java.lang.reflect.Field;
    import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    public class lineremoval {

        private static BufferedImage binarizedImage;


        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

            File orignal_name = new File("photot.png");
            binarizedImage = ImageIO.read(orignal_name);
            ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight();
        }
        public static int FindBottomOfLine(BufferedImage bitmap, int topOfLine)
        {
            int x=0;
            boolean no_black_pixel;
            no_black_pixel = false;
            int to_match;
            while (no_black_pixel == false)
            {
                topOfLine++;
                int white=new Color(bitmap.getRGB(0,0)).getRed();
                no_black_pixel = true; 
                for (x = 0; x < bitmap.getWidth() && topOfLine < bitmap.getHeight(); x++)
                {
                    to_match = new Color(bitmap.getRGB(x,topOfLine)).getRed();
                    if (to_match!=white)
                        no_black_pixel = false;
                }
            }
            return topOfLine - 1;
        }
        public static int  ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight()
        {
            int y = 0;
            int x = 0;
            boolean line_present = true;
            ArrayList<Integer> line_top = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000);
            ArrayList<Integer> line_bottom = new ArrayList<Integer>(1000);
            while (line_present)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = FindNextLine(binarizedImage, y, x);
                if (y == -1)
                    break;
                if (y >= binarizedImage.getHeight())
                {
                    line_present = false;
                }
                if (line_present)
                {
                    line_top.add(y);
                    y = FindBottomOfLine(binarizedImage, y) + 1;
                    line_bottom.add(y);
                }
            }


            BufferedImage    bmp = new BufferedImage(binarizedImage.getWidth(), binarizedImage.getHeight(),binarizedImage.getType());
                            for(int i=0; i<binarizedImage.getWidth(); i++) {
                            for(int j=0; j<binarizedImage.getHeight(); j++) {
                    int red;
                    red = new Color(binarizedImage.getRGB(i,j)).getRed();
                    int alpha = new Color(binarizedImage.getRGB(i,j)).getAlpha();
                    int newPixel;
                    newPixel = colorToRGB(alpha, red,red,red);
                    bmp.setRGB(i, j, newPixel);

                    }
                    }
                    writeImage(bmp,0);


            return 1;
        }
        private static void writeImage(BufferedImage bmp,int number) throws IOException {
            String strI = Integer.toString(number); 
            File file = new File("output"+strI+".png");
            try {
                    ImageIO.write(bmp, "png", file);
            }catch(IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("Not worked");
            }
            finally {
                    System.out.println("Works fine");
            }

        }
        private static int colorToRGB(int alpha, int red, int green, int blue) {

            int newPixel = 0;
            newPixel += alpha;
            newPixel = newPixel << 8;
            newPixel += red; newPixel = newPixel << 8;
            newPixel += green; newPixel = newPixel << 8;
            newPixel += blue;

            return newPixel;

        }
        public static int FindNextLine(BufferedImage bitmap, int y,int x)
        {
            if (y >= bitmap.getHeight())
                return -1;
            int white=new Color(bitmap.getRGB(0,0)).getRed();
            int to_match = new Color(bitmap.getRGB(x,y)).getRed();
            while (to_match==white)
            {

                x++;
                if (x == bitmap.getWidth())
                {
                    x = 0;
                    y++;
                }
                if (y >= bitmap.getHeight())
                {
                    break;
                }
                to_match = new Color(bitmap.getRGB(x,y)).getRed();
            }
            return y < bitmap.getHeight() ? y : -1;
        }

    }
```

I want to get x images from a bitmap Images containing x lines of paragraph.
each Image should contain one line from the paragraph.For this I have used function("ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight") to get two lists. In these lists ith element denotes the starting row no and end row no of ith line in paragraph (in list list_top and list_bottom).

After getting these values I am not able create Images from function ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight .

My code1 creates Images but code2 gives error both code are same the only difference is in code2 I have called writeImage from function "ExtractBeltsBasedonCoveredHeight" and in code1 I have called writeImage from main function

***ERROR MESSAGE***

```
lineremoval.java:86: error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                writeImage(bmp,0);
                          ^
1 error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is (as usual) telling you exactly what is wrong and how to fix it. You're calling code that has the potential to call an IOException, and when you do this you *must* either throw the exception or catch it in a try/catch block. Your best bet is to check out the exceptions tutorial to learn how to do both of these.

Comment: But why My code1 is working.Are you saying My code2 gives error but not able to throw

Comment: @stranger001: look at the methods that call the `writeImage(...)` methods. Do both throw the exception? Are you sure? Are you catching them anywhere?

Comment: My code Worked after adding (try catch and finally) in writeImage function but I still did not get why my code1 not gives eroor while code2 does.

Comment: @stranger001: again, because the method that calls the `writeImage(...)` method in code 1 *throws* the IOException, while the method in code 2 that calls `writeImage(...)` does not. I'm not sure how to explain this any other way that could make sense to you.